# Как пишется «латаное-перелатаное» (н/нн)?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, нн

1. лата**н**ое-перелата**н**ое
2. лата**н**ое-перелата**нн**ое
3. лата**нн**ое-перелата**нн**ое

Какой из трёх вариантов правильный?

Comment: Правильно: латаное-перелатаное. См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=латаный-перелатаный

Answer (score 2):

Правилен первый вариант.

См. ПАС:

**§ 99.** В словах с приставкой *не-,* в сложных словах и в некоторых сочетаниях-повторах формы причастий и прилагательных пишутся так же, как в отдельном (без приставки и не в составе сложного слова или сочетания-повтора) употреблении, т. е. по правилам § 98. Примеры:

<...>

3. Сочетания-повторы с приставкой *пере-* во второй части, имеющие усилительное значение. В них вторая часть пишется так же, как первая (с **нн** или **н**), напр.:

пишутся с **нн**: *заложенный-перезаложенный, решённый-перерешённый;*

пишутся с **н**: ***латаный-перелатаный**, стираный-перестираный, чиненый-перечиненый, читаный-перечитаный, штопаный-перештопаный.*

https://orfhographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52#pp52